# Symfony 2 - key/value entity structure and forms

Tags: symfony

I'm in need of design a settings entity. Basically, I'd like to have following structure of the table:

```
id
key
value
```

As you can see, dirty and simple design for storing application wide settings with key/value format.

Few issues I can't handle myself:
- how to deal with multiple types of content that can be stored in the field?
- how to deal with multiple types of form fields to be rendered & validated?
- the latest one, what would be the best way to render such form in Twig template?

Sorry for not being constructive here, I'm just out of clues and looking for a correct way to go.

**Edit**

As I was not clear enough in my question, I'd like to clarify some aspects of the issue:
- I'm wondering about the best idea of dealing with multiple types of value (integers, strings, texts, file paths)
- the second issue is related to the previous one: how should I generate the form for settings management? Should I store a field type in database? The amount of properties stored in the entity is unknown yet.

Best!

Comment: could you be a bit more precise what you're actually trying to do ... and in how far your simple settings entity relates to forms? What do you mean by `multiple types of content` ...

Comment: @nifr - I've updated my question, sorry for not being clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: To deal with different data types what about a json_encode call to save your data as a string preserving the original type?

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one data per field in your database.  You can add logic in your symfony entity to store everything as a string, but convert it as needed depending on the key.  You may need a second table with fields ID, key, value_type and this will have a one ot many relationship with your first table.